# Friend request not in friends requests list

Tags: facebook, facebook-friend-request

Last Thursday I talked with a lot of people, and 10 of them sent me a Facebook friend request (as my name is difficult to spell, they all actually made me type my name and press the "Add" button).

After leaving the place, I opened https://m.facebook.com on my Android's Chromium browser and as expected I had a red "10" on the requests icon, so I pressed it and pressed "Accept" for the 4 ones that were displayed. Problem: The others never got displayed, even after pressing the "Friend requests" icon again. I found it hard to believe but could only conclude that the other 6 had all canceled their requests.

A few days later (at my desktop computer), on a friend's post I randomly found Nana, one of the persons who had added me and whose request had seemingly vanished... but actually **it appears that Nana's request still exists**:

[image]

Puzzled, before accepting I clicked "Friend requests" then "See all" then clicked "More" until all got listed (200 friend requests in total, mostly colleagues and people I am not sure about): Searching for "Nana" in this list leads to zero result:

[image]

What is happening here?
Why are friend requests not appearing in my friend requests list?
Any workaround to see all recent friend requests? (so that I can find the 5 others beside Nana)

Comment: @pnuts: The "0 of 0" is just Chromium UI. I loaded the whole page then performed a browser in-page search to make sure the word is nowhere in the loaded page.