# List of people who have added me on Messenger, and I haven't accepted yet

Tags: facebook-messenger

Bob is a real life friend, but we are not connected at all on social media.

A few days ago, I got this *(on Android, but my question below is about the desktop website)*:

[image]

I was at work so I switched off my phone's screen (after taking the screenshot above as a memo). When the evening came, the message request was nowhere to be found, on mobile nor on the desktop website.

**Question**: Where to see a list of all pending New Message Requests?

Preferably on the desktop website. Please note that it is not simply a case of Bob canceling their request: Indeed, searching for Bob's name (luckily Bob's real name is very unique) lead me to their Facebook web profile page, and a click on "Message" revealed that the request is actually still pending:

[image]

I have not accepted yet, because I want to find out where a list of such requests is available. I wonder how many other unnoticed Message Requests I have pending.

Comment: Note: Different from my other question https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/107597/friend-request-not-in-friends-requests-list which is about Friend Requests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your screenshot I am assuming your are talking about Facebook Messenger app.

Please see following screenshot from the desktop app of pending message requests:

[image]
[image]

For your mobile app view the following screenshot:

[image]